# Ubuntu 32 Bit boot from USB but not installing

Tags: boot

I am installing Ubuntu on my pc which is 32-bit .i have tried a lot to boot it from USB but when I boot the USB the following screen appears.so how I can install ubuntu?

[image]

Comment: What happens before or after that screen? I don't see any errors. Can you go to "try Ubuntu" and click on install when the desktop loads?

Comment: when this screen appears the booting process stops here I wait for 30 minutes but nothing happens